# Mask Input validation with or condition for input field to enter either 5 digit or 9 digit:

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
  **$('.Phone').mask('Z', {
            translation: {
              'Z': { pattern: "^(([0-9]{5})|([0-9]{9}))$", optional: true, recursive: true}
            },
            maxlength: false
          });**
```

It does not work. Also, I am able to enter only 1 digit with above. I am Using 3rd party plugin **jQuery Mask Plugin v1.7.7**.
Also please recommend me links where mask and all its paramters explained with various examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for a number of either 5 or 9 digits using this regular expression:

```js
/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{9}$)/.test(val)
```

I don't know that plugin and never used it, but according to the [docs](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#mask-as-a-function) this should work:

```js
$('.phone').mask('Z', {
    translation: {'Z': { pattern: /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{9}$)/ } }
});
```

In my opinion you should avoid the other parameters: `maxlength`, `optional` (that for sure) and `recursive`.